# Akka.net persistence how to configure to go into recovery phase only after restart and not on start

Tags: persistence, akka.net

I have a persistent receive actor and supervision strategy to restart that actor in case of any exception. I am using snapshots and event journaling from akka.net persistence, and after restart everything works as expected. However, when my actor is started (not restarted) I don't want to recover any state from snapshot or journaled messages, so I don't want it to go into recovery and I can't find info on how to do that.

In akka.net documentation I found class Recovery, so my guess was I could do something like this

> var recovery = new Recovery(fromSnapshot: SnapshotSelectionCriteria.None, toSequenceNr: 0);

so I don't recover any snapshots or any messages, but I don't know how to let my actor know when to use that Recovery object, and how to make sure it uses default recovery behavior after restart.

Answer (score 0):

So you're right - the best way to customize this behavior inside your actor is to override the [`Recovery` property](https://getakka.net/api/Akka.Persistence.Eventsourced.html#Akka_Persistence_Eventsourced_Recovery)

Probably the best way to solve your problem is to do the following:

```
public class MyPersistentActor : PersistentActor{
   private Recovery _myRecovery;

   public virtual Recovery Recovery => _myRecovery ?? Recovery.None;

   protected override void PostRestart(Exception reason){
      _myRecovery = new YourRecovery();
      base.PostRestart(reason);
   }
}
```

You'll want to override the `PostRestart` method since that's called on the *new* actor instance being created after the actor has restarted, rather than the old actor instance. That should allow you to customize the runtime behavior.

Comment: The thing I was looking for was the Recovery property on EventSourced class, but the part with PostRestart isn't working correctly because the getter of property Recovery is invoked before PostRestart method is invoked. It is also invoked before PreStart when actor is starting, so I'm still not sure where would be the correct place to change the value of _myRecovery.

Comment: > PostRestart isn't working correctly because the getter of property Recovery is invoked before PostRestart

I was afraid of that - in that case, try using that same code in `AroundPostRestart` instead - I believe _that_ will get run before Akka.Persistence's recovery mechanism does.